# Why doDrop Shadow Filter displays fine in Chrome but render entire path not visible in firefox/IE

Tags: svg

I am rendering the  following svg dynamically

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"> 
<svg version="1.1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0,0,952,500" width="100%" >
<defs>
<filter id="plotShadow" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="offOut" result="matrixOut" values=" 
0 0 0 0 0.0
0 0 0 0 0.0 
0 0 0 0 0.0 
0 0 0 0.5 0">
</feColorMatrix>
<feOffset dx="4" dy="4" in="SourceAlpha" result="offOut"></feOffset>
<feGaussianBlur in="matrixOut" stdDeviation="5" result="blurOut">
</feGaussianBlur>
<feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal">
</feBlend></filter>
</defs>

<g fill="#000000" transform="translate(0,50)" class="lineClass">
<path fill="none" stroke="#00a4df" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="5" filter="url(#plotShadow)" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" d="M0 74.66666666666667 L180.62068030898502 74.66666666666667 L195.6055071198045 0 L633.9328734420252 0 L648.9177002528447 74.66666666666667 L772.8096753472835 74.66666666666667"></path>
</g>
</svg>
```

The image is displayed correctly in chrome (path visible with shadow), in IE or Firefox  the path is not visible at all.

If I remove filter="url(#plotShadow)" from the path definition then the path displays correctly in firefox and chrome albeit  without a shadow.

Can anyone help identify where my error is or explain why the svg is rendered differently in different browsers?

I have uploaded the code to codepen : [svg on codepen](https://codepen.io/barryj497/pen/wdpKjN)

Comment: I don't think your result and in values are valid. For instance you've two filter primitives with result="offOut"

Answer (score 1):

Fix your result/ins and enlarge the default filter region so you don't have clipping. (Note that this code will fail for pure vertical or horizontal lines. For these, you must explicitly specify filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" and dynamically calculate the correct x/y/width/height for the filter region in userSpace units.) Different browsers have more/less tolerance for malformed filter syntax.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"> 
<svg version="1.1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0,0,952,500" width="100%" >
<defs>
  <filter id="plotShadow" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" x="-50%" y="-50%" height="200%" width="200%">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="SourceGraphic" result="matrixOut" values="0 0 0 0 0.0
                   0 0 0 0 0.0 
                   0 0 0 0 0.0 
                   0 0 0 0.5 0"/>
    <feOffset dx="4" dy="4" in="matrixOut" result="offOut"/>
    <feGaussianBlur in="offOut" stdDeviation="5" result="blurOut"/>
    <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal"/>
  </filter>
</defs>

<g fill="#000000" transform="translate(0,50)" class="lineClass">
  <path fill="none" stroke="#00a4df" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="5" filter="url(#plotShadow)" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" d="M0 74.66666666666667 L180.62068030898502 74.66666666666667 L195.6055071198045 0 L633.9328734420252 0 L648.9177002528447 74.66666666666667 L772.8096753472835 74.66666666666667"></path>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: that still isn't visible in safari?

Comment: Right. There is a bug in Safari where the first value of the feColorMatrix values array must be immediately after the quotation mark. Fixed the code up there.

Comment: Still not visible in Safari

Comment: This live snippet works for me: Safari 10.1 on MacOSX 10.10.5 (hopefully you're not using Safari for Windows, that never supported filters and is end of life)

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your filter.  The first filter primitive (the `<feColorMatrix>`) specifies that its input should come from another primitive with the result named `"offOut"`.

```
<feColorMatrix ... in="offOut" .../>
```

But there is no such filter primitive (preceding it anyway).  Change it to `in="SourceGraphic"`, and it will work.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"> 
<svg version="1.1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0,0,952,500" width="100%" >
<defs>
  <filter id="plotShadow" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="SourceGraphic" result="matrixOut" values=" 
                   0 0 0 0 0.0
                   0 0 0 0 0.0 
                   0 0 0 0 0.0 
                   0 0 0 0.5 0"/>
    <feOffset dx="4" dy="4" in="SourceAlpha" result="offOut"/>
    <feGaussianBlur in="matrixOut" stdDeviation="5" result="blurOut"/>
    <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal"/>
  </filter>
</defs>

<g fill="#000000" transform="translate(0,50)" class="lineClass">
  <path fill="none" stroke="#00a4df" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="5" filter="url(#plotShadow)" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" d="M0 74.66666666666667 L180.62068030898502 74.66666666666667 L195.6055071198045 0 L633.9328734420252 0 L648.9177002528447 74.66666666666667 L772.8096753472835 74.66666666666667"></path>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: even this is wrong as there are two filter primitives with result="offOut"

Comment: Correct, but the second one doesn't matter becaue it is the last primitive. I will fix.

Comment: Shouldn't the feGaussianBlur take offOut rather than matrixOut?

Comment: I was concentrating only on the fact that it was broken in FF.  Since the OP said that it was working "correctly" in Chrome, I guess the answer is "maybe"? :)  But since it is now functioning in both browsers, he may notice that the offset is not working...

Comment: it works in firefox now but not, android browser (path not visible), safari (shadow not visible)